# Why many PHP developers use "__DIR__ . '../otherFolder'"?

Tags: php, relative-path, dir

Often I see this type of code `__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'`. But why is the point, am I wrong that is it the same that typing `../Resources/config'` ?

Comment: You're right, in this case, it's the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not always the same thing. `__DIR__` is the directory of the *file*, not the current working directory. This code is essentially a dynamically-generated *absolute* path.

Write this into `~/foo/script.php`:

```
<?php
// Ta, Sven
//  https://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php#84012
function get_absolute_path($path) {
    $path = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
    $parts = array_filter(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path), 'strlen');
    $absolutes = array();
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if ('.' == $part) continue;
        if ('..' == $part) {
            array_pop($absolutes);
        } else {
            $absolutes[] = $part;
        }
    }
    return '/' . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $absolutes);
}

$p = __DIR__ . '/../bar';
echo $p . "\n" . get_absolute_path($p) . "\n";
?>
```

Now:

```
$ cd ~/foo
$ php script.php
/home/me/foo/../bar
/home/me/bar

$ cd ~/
$ php foo/script.php
/home/me/foo/../bar
/home/me/bar
```

*But* if we got rid of `__DIR__`:

```
$ cd ~/foo
$ php script.php
../bar
/home/me/bar

$ cd ~/
$ php foo/script.php
../bar
/home/bar
```

See ... that last path is incorrect.

If we were using these paths anywhere, they'd be broken without `__DIR__`.

Whenever you write a script, you should ensure that it is safe to execute it from some directory other than the one in which it lives!

Comment: Thanks but can you give more uses cases ?

Comment: It's hard to see how this could be any clearer, or what any other examples would show

Comment: is that the only reason you use __DIR__? In case the the script is executed from other directories? is there other reasons why you would use __DIR__?

Comment: @Soujirou I think in case of classes as well

Comment: @Soujirou: Since `__DIR__` (not "**DIR**") gives you the script's directory, it stands to reason that whether you use it or not will affect things that relate to directories. Really, this seems like more than enough of a reason. Large PHP projects have files `include`d from different directories all over the place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604445/php-absolute-path-to-root, I was talking about this

Comment: @AkshendraPratap: What does that have to do with classes?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I am sorry if I am not clear. Again what I meant is that if you access a file inside a class using relative path, then this path is being resolved from the script where the object of this class is being instantiated. That's the problem is the linked question isn't it?

Comment: @AkshendraPratap: No, it has nothing to do with classes. You're just extending the original problem: relative directory paths when evaluated from a different directory. The same happens with code in a non-class function. And with code that's not in a function at all. The fact that you can put that code into a class method is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

Because in many cases the relative path won't work, for example when the script is run from some other folder. Using [__ DIR __](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) converts the relative path into absolute path, leaving no space for any confusion.

For your question lets suppose this hierarchy,

```
/
test/
test/script.php
test/Resource/config
another/
```

Now `script.php` contains this path, you run the script from the directory `test` so the relative path is resolved to `test/Resource/config`. Its what you wanted.

But if you run the script from say `another`, then the path will be resolved to `another/Resource/config` which is not right.

If you have used `__DIR__`, it always get resolved into the path of the script that it is used in. So the relative path would have become /test/Resource/config

Now no matter from where you run this script, since the path is absolute, it won't be resolved relatively and will remain the same.

Comment: Can you be more verbose please :) ?

Comment: I understand what you say but can you please give me different examples?

Comment: @rickozoe: If you understand it, I'm sure you can spend some time coming up with the examples yourself. And you will learn something in the process.

Comment: Thank you for this ! I understand now.