# When i use php include the path is not correct but in server it works perfectly

Tags: php, include, require, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a project with so many php includes and requires , when i downloaded all the file from the server to my localhost , the pages where not loading correctly , i found out it was because of the path in include and require funtions

when i gave in my view file

`require 'models/topic_db.php';`

its working correctly but my folder is actually like this `admin/models/topic_db.php` and in my view file is at `admin/views/topic.php`

and in my server it works like this

`require '../models/topic_db.php';`

I dont understand what the issue is , but all the pages are having similar issue so i can't go to each page and fix it , so i need a common solution , is there a way i can fix it without editing each and every file ?

for the record this is also working `require(dirname(__DIR__).'/models/topic_db.php');`

But in all my codes the format is like this `require '../models/topic_db.php';`

Any way i can fix it using .htaccess ?

Right now my .htaccess looks like this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ index.php [NC]
```

And my project is at

**C:\xampp\htdocs\live\project**

[Image to get an idea of the folder path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4RVq.png)

```
<?php

session_start();
//include ('../../config.php');
include(dirname(__DIR__).'../config.php');

require_once(dirname(__DIR__).'../system/core/coreModel.php');
//require_once '../../system/core/coreModel.php';
$db = new coreModel();
$conn = $db->connectDb();
?>
```

Comment: Create a Virtual Host for your site to run in that matches the directory structure on you LIVE site. Running out of `locahost/folder` is not the same structure as your live site

Comment: i am using xampp to run this php project

Comment: check your DocumentRoot , make certain your local web server points to the same place as the server.

Comment: In my server it is /var/www/html and inside it has this admin folder

Comment: Is ur localhost runs on windows and server is is linux?

Comment: yes my localhost run on windows and server is in linux

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178263/make-a-path-work-both-on-linux-and-windows ....See this...they both treat path differently...So better to change the path as given in the answer.. Also refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604445/php-absolute-path-to-root

Comment: Let me check any other way you know that of?

Answer (score 0):

Why it is working In Server because there is two dots in :

```
require '../models/topic_db.php';
```

which denotes one folder inside.It should be as :

```
require 'models/topic_db.php';
```

Comment: in server it is working correct but in localhost same code is not working why is that ? any idea?

Comment: r u using same line require '../models/topic_db.php';  in localhost  ?

Comment: then it would be coded in your .htaccess file . i guess.Please edit your question with some code.

Comment: in .htaccess only this is there Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ index.php [NC]

Comment: check now i have added , is that enough ?

Comment: Check  a sample code , the commented codes are not working