# How to go from one page to another page when Ajax call is on in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, queue

> **How to continue run ajax call after redirect to another page in PHP?**
>
> **How to go from one page to another page when Ajax call is on in PHP?**

My **ajax** call is performing a very **complex** task and it will take a **longtime** So, Is it possible to **run** an **ajax** call **after** page redirect?

I make **ajax** call on **submit** button **click** and after that page **redirects** on another page and then my **ajax** call is **Continue Running** in Backend.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" name="altname" id="altname">
  <button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#btnSubmit',function(){ 
    var altname = $("#altname").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/z/backend-queue-job-php/queue_job.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{altname:altname},
            success:function(result)
            {   
                alert(result.msg);
            }
        });
        window.location.href = "http://localhost/z/backend-queue-job-php/thankyoupage.php";
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simpler way to run a PHP script in background is with exec or shell_exec

You can run following function in a php file which is called via ajax, passing the path of your current script with a log path if you want to store log info:

```
shell_exec("/path/to/php /path/to/queue_job.php > /path_to_log/debug.log 2>&1");
```

Comment: shell_exec("/path/to/php /path/to/queue_job.php 'alert' > in this case path in which?

Comment: which path you're asking about? all must be absolute path (not URL) in above command.

Comment: you can get absolute paths of your php files as mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604445/php-absolute-path-to-root

Comment: this is not work i try this.... 
my case in first script execute , load page , script done  after page is redirect
so, any other idea..!

Answer (score 1):

It can only be done using async task in your PHP part.

- Assign an ID for every task
- Your ajax will create new task or fetch the status of existing task