# Way to get absolute path of file PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the absolute path of a file while having it included in another script?

So I'm trying to include a file that's in folder A while I'm in folder B but it keeps trying to refer to folder B's location.

I've tried `dirname`, `$SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, `cwd()`, but they still return a relative path.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952590/php-how-to-find-application-root

Comment: try this echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy No, that only gives me up to `/var/www/html`. My file is nested within a couple more folders in.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can try like this

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../yourfile.php';
```

Since PHP 5.3.0 you can use also the magic constant `__DIR__` [More info in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Another way is

```
$rootDir = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

include "$rootDir/yourfile.php";
```

Comment: +1 for the options! that made me think of this (common?) line: `$base_dr = basename(__DIR__);` (where the directory at the top of the structure drives biz logic somehow).

Comment: for some strange reason `$rootDir = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/../yourfile.php' );` will not work

Answer (score 16):

**`__FILE__`**

That is the absolute path to the file being executed.

> *simple usage examples:*
>
> `echo __FILE__;`
>
> `echo "This file is: " . __FILE__;`

Comment: This is simpler and easy to remember

Answer (score 2):

If you need the real path you can use the SplFileInfo.

```
$path = new SplFileInfo(__FILE__);
echo 'The real path is '.$path->getRealPath();
```